# Binding Nested Observable Collection in xaml using c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I am having a hard time trying to figure out how to bind in xaml a nested Observable Collection.  The PLC class contains Tags.  This might be familiar if you work in Automation.  I have marked the areas of code I am having trouble with by saying "***!Can't Figure this out***".  I am new to xaml and trying to do the binding in the xaml.  If it can't be done in the xaml, a code behind solution would be helpful.

**PLC Class**

```
public class PLC
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public PLC(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Tags = new ObservableCollection<Tag>();
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

**Tag Class** The PLC's tags when you click on a PLC  the ListView to the right will get the tags associated with that PLC.

```
public class Tag
{
    public Tag(string name, int value)
    {
        Name = name;
        Value = value;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

**xaml** - note this is a user control binded to the parent's viewmodel.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.UserControls.RuntimeControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Margin="10,0,0,0" >Runtime</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ListView x:Name="PLCLV" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" FontSize="25" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding PLCs}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            <ListView Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" FontSize="25" AlternationCount="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      BorderThickness="0 " ItemsSource=***!Can't Figure this out!***>
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text = "Name: "/>
                            <Run Text =***!Can't Figure this out!***
                            <Run Text ="Value: "/>
                            <Run Text =***!Can't Figure this out!***
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**FIX in the UserControl xaml Answer Marked as accepted**

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" FontSize="25" 
DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=PLCLV}" 
ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}">
```

Comment: What is the second `ListView` supposed to show, exactly?  A list of tags, that's clear but of whose Tags?

Comment: @Joe Thank you for the question.  Each PLC has a list of tags associated with it.  The ListView on the right is to show the tags  of the PLC that is selected on the left side.  In that ListView I am hoping to show both the tag and it's value.  I have a LOT more code that reads tags from the plc I just didn't think it was needed for this example.  Already feels like I have too much code.

Comment: In that case, what you need is a view-model property named, say `SelectedPlc` to indicate the currently selected item.  This property should live in whatever view-model holds the list of PLCs (the property you've literally  named `PLCs`.)  Bind the first ListView's ("PLCLV") `SelectedItem` property to this view-model property.  Then your second view-model can set its `ItemsSource` to bind to `SelectedItem.Tags`

Comment: Hi @Joe, I think I mostly understand.  Except the very last part.  Both ListViews bind to the same ViewModel.  I have ViewModel for two UserControls also for MainWindow .  Yesterday I couldn't figure out how to bind a UserControl to a ViewModel since they don't have DataContext like a window does. I finally found a post that said it inherits from the Window it is on.  I haven't had any Luck binding to any class.property that is why I posted this question.  But I think you are saying SelectedItem should be bound to PLCs ObserevableCollection Tags.  Thank you for all your time.

Comment: @Joe Also if you like since I'm not getting much traction on this question.  I searched all over for a good answer.  Could you please answer so I can mark your suggestion as the answer.  I was looking for a xaml only solution but, said if code behind (the ViewModel) is the only way I will be happy with that.

Comment: Yes they both bind to the same view-model but they should bind their respective `ItemsSource` properties to different *properties* of that view-model.  The first already binds its `ItemsSource` to `PLCs`, right?  All I am saying is that you should create another public property in that view-model that represents the currently selected item of that first `ListView`.  Then the second ListView will bind to that selected item's `Tags`

Comment: In fact, you don't even need a backing, view-model property for the selected item.  The second `ListView`could bind directly to the the first `ListView`'s selected item, like this  `ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=PLCLV, Path=SelectedItem.Tags}"`

Comment: @Joe I think the comment above is what Mr. Squirrel.Downy   did as his other solution.  I have to get sleep now.  Are either of you available tomorrow.  It's suggesting taking it into chat.  I could also look into posting my Solution on https://github.com/ if either of you want to take a more careful look.  It's a bit much to post all of it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you set the ItemsSource by list of PLC on "PLCLV" named ListView , so the type of object in SelectedItem of this ListView must be PLC type (or null), you can make this SelectedItem be the source of Tag list.

```
            <ListView Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" FontSize="25" AlternationCount="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      BorderThickness="0 " ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Tags, ElementName=PLCLV}">
            <!-- Or SelectedItem.(local:PLC.Tags), the "(local:PLC.Tags)" means "the speicified property of specified type on unspecified type boxed property" -->
            <!-- you can use Binding.ElementName to find the sepcified "Name/x:Name" named element in visual tree to be the Binding source -->
                <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <!-- "x:Type" is a speicial markup for return a specific "Type" object -->
                    <!-- Set DataType of DataTemplate can help XAML editor show IntelliSense to help you -->
                    <!-- "local:" is a prefix of namespace for the type in xml, defined by "xmlns:", here make the editor know the this DataTemplate is apply on the "Tag" type -->
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Tag}">
                        <TextBlock>
                            <Run Text="Name: "/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Run Text="Value: "/>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Value}" />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Or, use DataContext and ItemsSource:

```
<ListView Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" FontSize="25" AlternationCount="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          BorderThickness="0"
          DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=PLCLV}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}">
          <!-- Or ItemsSource="{Binding Path=(local:PLC.Tags)}" -->
...
```

Comment: @captcpsc Do not comment "Thanks", upvote and accpet answer is a more right way in here.

Comment: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Tags' property not found on 'object' ''ObservableCollection`1' (HashCode=34280961)'. BindingExpression:Path=Tags; DataItem='ObservableCollection`1' (HashCode=34280961); target element is 'ListView' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: When I tried
            <ListView Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" FontSize="25" AlternationCount="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      BorderThickness="0" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=PLCLV, Path=SelectedItem.Tags}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}">

Comment: 'Test.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\3.1.29\System.Collections.Immutable.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
I used
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test.Model"
 on top of the user control

Comment: @captcpsc update your quesion to tell us what's new wrong with you.

Comment: Oh... wait... Look at your code: `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=PLCLV, Path=SelectedItem.Tags}" ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}"`. What's are you doing? the property `DataContext` always be the default binding source of current and child element, if have not set the property named `Source/ElementName/RelativeSource` of `Binding`, it will use the DataContext value as source. You setted `DataContext="{Binding ElementName=PLCLV, Path=SelectedItem.Tags}"`. DataContext is the collection of Tag now, not PLC object! So that's why you try to seek the property `Tags` on the collection got fail.

Comment: I did not think your updated solution would work.  I did mess up with the binding.  BUT, I fixed it and tried it again.  IT WORK!  I am very happy.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the DataContext of the UserControl is set correctly (i.e. the binding of `PLCs` is correct)

Add this property in code behind under `PLCs` collection property (probably you will need it later in code behind)

```
private PLC _selectedPlc;
public PLC SelectedPlc
{
    get => _selectedPlc;
    set 
    {
        _selectedPlc = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedPlc)); // this will update the second ListView
    }
}
public ObservableCollection PLCs {set; get;} // you have this already
```

The first ListView can see all PLCs.. Let's bind the DataContext of the second ListView with `SelectedPlc` property, this way, the second ListView will only see one PLC.

```
<ListView x:Name="PLCLV" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10" FontSize="25" SelectionMode="Single" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          BorderThickness="0" ItemsSource="{Binding PLCs}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlc}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>

<ListView Grid.Column="1" Margin="10" FontSize="25" AlternationCount="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
          BorderThickness="0" 
          DataContext="{Binding SelectedPlc}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Tags}">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="false"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text= "Name: "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Name}"
                <Run Text="Value: "/>
                <Run Text="{Binding Value}"
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Do not forget to fill `PLCs` (and `Tags` inside each PLC) collections with some data!

Note: there is `ForegroundColor` property missing in your PLC class!

Comment: Muhammad Sulaiman Thank you for your help.  If I could upvote your Answer I would.  However Mr. Squirrel.Downy had a xaml only solution that worked!